# how to pass big data to google scatter chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, bigdata

I am relatively new to JavaScript and Django and I am struggling with passing big data to my google chart.

I have a chart representing velocities for a given date and distance. In my django views I create list of distances, dates and according velocities. I also generate there a list with sorted values occuring in velocity list and a list with colors according to velocity's value.

I want to have a chart with velocity map with applied colortable like this : 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwzJV.jpg

So I used scatter chart with velocity series. The chart is dynamic, it's diffrent for every item selected by a user.

JS to generate rows and columns :

```
// Define data table rows:
  var rows = [];
  var rows_list = [];
  var vl_max = vel_list.length;
  for (i=0; i < vl_max; i+=1) {
      var date_tmp = new Date(date_list[i].split(',')[0],date_list[i].split(',')[1]-1,date_list[i].split(',')[2]);
      var date = [date_tmp];
      var vel_tmp = vel_list[i];
      var vtemp_max = vel_tmp.length;
      var tooltip_dsname = dsname_list[i];
      var tooltip_track = track_list[i];
      for (j=0; j < vtemp_max; j+=1) {
        var cell = [{v : date_tmp}]; 
        for (k=0; k < vr_max; k+=1) {
          var vel_full = vel_tmp[j];
          var vel = vel_full.toFixed(1);
          if (vel == vel_range[k]) {
          // tooltip:
          var dist = dist_list[j]/1000;
          var yyyy = date_tmp.getFullYear().toString();
          var mm = (date_tmp.getMonth()+1).toString(); // getMonth() is zero-based
          var dd = date_tmp.getDate().toString();
          var tooltip_date = yyyy + "-" + (mm[1]?mm:"0"+mm[0]) + "-" + (dd[1]?dd:"0"+dd[0]);
          var tooltip = "<b>dataset: </b>"+tooltip_dsname+"<br><b>date: </b>"+tooltip_date+"<br><b>track: </b>"+tooltip_track+"<br><b>distance: </b>"+dist+" k"+mapunit+"<br><b> velocity: </b>"+vel_full.toFixed(2)+" m/d";
          var color = color_list[k]
          var style = "point { shape-type: square; fill-color: "+color+";}"
          } else {
            var dist = NaN;
            var tooltip = "empty" ;
            var style = "empty" ;
          }
          cell.push({v: dist},{v: tooltip},{v:style});
      }
      rows_list.push({c: cell});

      }
  };
```

Here is JSfiddle for chart generation with smaller data :
http://jsfiddle.net/joannao89/t26ooyrt/2/

The problem that I have is while the chart is working for smaller data, once I want to load it for a long distance and a wide date range, the browser keeps on popping us this line : "A website is slowing down your browser, what would you like to do ? {stop} {wait}"

I know that this is probably the problem of too large amount of rows, my website generates also 3 other charts like this, with the same data but in another X-Y axis combination (for example time on X-axis, velocity on Y-axis and distance as series) and it works perfectly fine. That's why I would like to pass the data to the chart in some faster way, but I have no clue how.

I already tried to use `setTimeout`, but it doesn't change a lot. I also tried doing a little less coding on JS side and more in django views, but it also didn't help.

So any suggestions about how to solve this will be very appreciated!

Comment: recommend building entire json needed for the data table in Django, [in this format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#dataparam), then create the google data table in JavaScript straight from the json -- avoid any per row manipulation, use google's data view for calculated columns or filters...

Comment: Done, but the window keeps on popping up ...